# Album Names in Photos app

Tags: photos.app

I moved from iPhoto to Photos, and now I can't see the albums arranged by name in the sidebar. All that organizing is gone! Is there a view where I can still see my list of albums?

Comment: Can you see the sidebar itself? It defaults to off, but toggles with Cmd/alt/s. iPhoto Albums should be directly in the list, with Events subfoldered, as Photos doesn't use them

Answer (score 1):

As Tetsujin said, Command,alt,S works to toggle the sidebar, but alternatively you should be able to access you albums from the top middle of the screen (third button over):
[image]